# Select data from multiple tables in RDS using DataPipeline

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, amazon-data-pipeline

Is there a way (using existing templates) to select data from multiple tables by joining them using AWS datapipeline. My usecase requires me to combine data from multiple RDS tables to export to Redshift.

For eg. RDS has Tables School, Student, District. I want to export data like:-

```
select sch.Name, stu.Name, dis.Name from School sch inner join Student stu on stu.schoolid = sch.id inner join District dis on dis.id = sch.districtid;
```

Is there a way in AWS Datapipeline for me to select data from multiple tables ?

Comment: You're selecting 3 columns all called `Name`.  The source table identity would be lost, making the column names ambiguous. Try `select sch.Name AS school_name, stu.Name AS student_name, dis.Name AS district_name ...` perhaps?

Answer (score 1):

There is a field name "select Query" in Data node. You can write your transformation SQL which can pull out data from different tables.

Please refer below image.

[Select Query in Data Node](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WLtUu.png)

Comment: Data Node allows only 1 table name in "table" field. If we are to join multiple tables to fetch data, don't we need to specify multiple tables?

Comment: No there is no need to mention all tables.
select * from tablename1 JOIN tablename2 will work.

Comment: What do you suggest in case we need to migrate whole DB? Using JOIN sounds is a workaround i guess.

Comment: @vivekyad4v  If you want to put multiple tables of source data in a single destination table, you have to perform join.  To migrate whole db you can create a single pipeline or break this into multiple pipelines. It would be good to create a separate pipeline for each table in the destination database. The number of pipelines depends on your schema of the destination database.

Comment: Is this possible for Incremental Back up Method as well?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a single pipeline that will have different activities for each table that you want to replicate.
This way, you won't have to write join query to replicate multiple tables.

Answering to an old question, so that it can help others still searching for something like this.